# Finding A Child Control Based On X & Y Coordinate in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

In Flex/Actionscript

When writing an on mouseMove event on a Canvas control for example, how could I check to see what control if any is under the mouse pointer at a particular coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call getObjectsUnderPoint on your Canvas to determine what children of that canvas are under the current mouse point.  You have to make sure the point you pass in is in stage coordinates.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Good answer. If you had the local point, you could probably use the localToGlobal to find the stage coordinates